# How to sorted by treemap key's length,if key's length are equal make it alphabetically and write to text file

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I have a problem how to continue, anyone help may code?

Let me know the basic concept too ...

```
readfile data => IBARAKI MitoCity
             TOCHIGI UtunomiyaCity
             GUNMA MaehashiCity
             SAITAMA SaitamaCity
             CHIBA ChibaCity
             TOKYO Sinjyuku
             KANAGAWA YokohamaCity
write text file output => CHIBA : ChibaCity
                     GUNMA : MaehashiCity
                     TOKYO : Sinjyuku
                     IBARAKI : MitoCity
                     SAITAMA : SaitamaCity
                     TOCHIGI : UtunomiyaCity
                     KANAGAWA : YokohamaCity
```

### Code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ReadFileDemo{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new 
    FileInputStream(args[0]),"UTF-8");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new 
    FileOutputStream("textB.txt"),"UTF-8");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);        
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

    String line=null;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
     String[] parts = line.split(" ");
     String key=parts[0];
          String value=parts[1];
          map.put(key,value);
    }

    Map<String, String> treemap = new TreeMap<String, String>(map);

   }
}
```

*Thanks!!*

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of keys (or use the map's keySet), then write your own Comparator to sort that list, then iterate over the sorted List to create your output file.

The Comparator might look like this:

```
public class Cmp1 implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if(o1.length() == o2.length()) {
            //String's own comparator, which is alphabetical
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
        //otherwise compare the length
        return o2.length() - o1.length();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Or, as the other answers point out, pass that Comparator to the constructor of tree map.

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply your own comparator to the `TreeMap`:

```
Map<String, String> treemap = new TreeMap<>(myComparator);
```

Then add all elements to the new `TreeMap`:

```
treemap.addAll(map);
```

Or even better, use a TreeMap in the first place for varibale `map`. So it would not be necessary to copy the Contents of `map` to a new `TreeMap`.

A simple way to make the comparator is using the functions in class `java.util.Comparator`:

```
Comparator<String> myComparator = comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(naturalOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java `TreeMap` has a Constructor `new TreeMap(Comparator<? super K>)`. So you could just instantiate a `TreeMap` with a `Comparator` sorting like you wish and then put directly to this `TreeMap`. When you iterate over the EntrySet of this Map the elements will be in the order you need.

Your Comparator in Java-8-functional-style can be written as

```
Comparator.comparing(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareTo);
```